# Two questions about mathematical platonism

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, foundations-of-mathematics, platonism

Any set, number, shape, definition, axiom, etc we write down or think about is not the ideal platonic version. But surely the mathematical platonist thinks humans are closer to that unreachable goal in some sense than in the past, since at one time we didn’t have numbers, geometry, or set theory. We are progressively more aware. (1) Driven to its conclusion, isn’t the eventuality  of this picture like asking of something to study or be the reason for itself, or at least something arbitrary close to itself? We are using math, which is endlessly getting “better” or “acquiring more knowledge of the forms”, to study the forms.

(2) The unreachability of the ideal platonic and yet the endlessness of mathematics. They never meet and yet get infinitely closer. Infinitely closer because math seems infinitely able to generate new knowledge. More knowledge the forms or abstract objects themselves. That seems like modern math is a model of how humans might become more and more aware of the forms/abstract objects. Infinite series, limits, and this picture of mathematicians endlessly getting closer to the abstract, *have very similar structure*. If we don’t presuppose abstract objects we might endlessly get closer to, would limits and infinite series be so prominent?

So two main questions, first is about how can we entertain A explaining A (or arbitrarily close to A). That if, like real numbers, mathematicians can get infinitely close to the forms, is there a danger of, if forms are ultimate reasons, how something arbitrarily close to “itself” be the reason for itself. Like a danger of autopeoesis. This seems like not a danger of non-infinite mathematics. And second is about did we create some features of modern math like limits and infinite series (and maybe even set theory) because they model the process of a human coming closer to the good but never reaching it? In imagining humans endlessly striving toward some unreachable, but always able to make progress/get closer to it. I’d argue a constructivist might never have such a notion of infinitely getting no lower but never reaching, and might never on her own develop some feature of modern math.

Here is a quote by Michael Friedman that hopefully alludes to these two questions. “We can only strive to instantiate perfect beauty, justice, wisdom, etc by successive approximations that continually approach but never actually achieve our ideal goal. “ https://youtu.be/31Bowz6DDFQ?t=12m21s (I haven’t watched much further yet).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134979/discussion-on-question-by-j-kusin-two-questions-about-mathematical-platonism).

Comment: I have since found some reviews of Badiou saying ZFC ST is ontology. That it both captures  “multiplicity on multiplicity” and other aspects infinity and wins out among competing formalisms like category T for sociological reasons. What I was asking about in my Q is a case (platonism) where the structure of an ontology (in the widest sense ontology) closely mirrors a mathematical formalism. In my Q it was if “striving toward something” (“platonism”)is similar to limits. Badious’ ontological and mathematical structure are different than my Q, but both share that their ontological structure

Comment: claimed closely mirrors structure in their ontologys’ most  cherished formalism/subject of math.